# ResultSetMetaData getTableName return empty

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata, resultset

I am trying to get TableName from ResultSetMetaData by following code:

```
 `Properties info = new java.util.Properties(); 
                    info.put ("user",this.username); 
                    info.put ("password",this.password); 
                    info.put ("ResultSetMetaDataOptions","1");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,info);

                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                                    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                                    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
                                    metaData.getTableName(0);
                                    for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                        logger.info("Table Name : " + metaData.getTableName(i);)
                                    }`
```

I follow this link:         https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/jdbc_drivers/oracle.html#1075290

But,getTableName return  still empty.

How to set ResultSetMetaDataOptions? 
How can I select tableName with other method ?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using? You are linking to very old documentation, and I know Oracle removed some of the metadata options from more recent drivers because of the limited usefulness and impact on performance. Also what is the query you are executing?

Comment: My ojdbc version: <dependency>
   <groupId>oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0.3</version>
  </dependency>  and my sql query : select * from TABLE_A a , TABLE_B b  where 
a.sameColumn = b.sameColumn;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you link is for a very old driver. A recent version of the Oracle JDBC driver documentation explicitly states, in [Using Result Set Metadata Extensions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/accessing-and-manipulating-Oracle-data.html#GUID-C9AF8539-12BA-4F19-AAB9-0EE481D78F19):

> The `oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSetMetaData` interface is JDBC
>   2.0-compliant but does not implement the `getSchemaName` and `getTableName` methods because Oracle Database does not make this
>   feasible.

In other words, you can't get this data for Oracle.